# How to understand the missing transverse energy in the $t\bar{t}$ decay?

Tags: particle-physics, energy-conservation, standard-model, quarks

Let's consider the process $gg \rightarrow t\bar{t}$ and the subsequent decay of the $t$ quark into a $W^{-}b$ respectively. Now, if we consider the leptonic + jets decay mode of the $W^{-}$ boson, for example, then we clearly get a neutrino, e.g. a $\bar{\nu}_{e^{-}}$.

**Question**: [This CMS plot](https://cds.cern.ch/record/2712889/files/ttbar_mtt500.png?subformat=icon-1440) has an example for the decay $t\bar{t}\rightarrow W^{-}bW^{+}\bar{b} \rightarrow q\bar{q}^{'}b\mu^{+}\nu_{\mu^{+}}\bar{b}$. Where do we know from how much missing transverse energy we have?

Comment: What are you asking exactly? How is $E_T$ measured or what it means?

Comment: Put (overly) simply, you can add up all traverse energies. Since the detector is hermetic and measures energy in all directions, if you have a net apparent violation of energy, that points to missing (traverse) energy, and thus to a particle that left undetected. But does that actually answer your question?

Comment: see these answers https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/592285/high-transverse-momentum-physics/592383#592383   , https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/323392/what-are-transverse-momentum-cuts-for/324227#324227 https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/411167/can-we-tell-something-about-rest-mass-from-this-plot-of-differential-cross-secti/411179#411179

Comment: @rfl Sorry, I totally understand what $E_T$ is. But in the example of the CMS plot I asked, how can I calculate it for that specific example? Because when I add up the $p_T$ from all other particles, I get $p_T = 378.2$ GeV and so I thought $E_T = - 378.2$ GeV...

Comment: @Anonymous5638: The reason why E_T is not -378.2 GeV is that pT is a vector quantity. So, you need to add them vectorially then get its magnitude.